# R How to loop over all character variables in a data.frame and change a specific value

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to loop over all the variables in a data.table and modify all the character variables; some of the values of these character variables are 'NULL', and I want to change them to ''.

For example: I want to change

```
    library(data.table)
    df <- data.table('id' = seq(1:10),
             'datadate' = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2015-01-10'), by="days"),
             'charvar' = c('a', 'b', 'c', rep('NULL', 7)),
             'charvar1' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', rep('NULL', 6)))



    id   datadate charvar charvar1
 1:  1 2015-01-01       a        a
 2:  2 2015-01-02       b        b
 3:  3 2015-01-03       c        c
 4:  4 2015-01-04    NULL        d
 5:  5 2015-01-05    NULL     NULL
 6:  6 2015-01-06    NULL     NULL
 7:  7 2015-01-07    NULL     NULL
 8:  8 2015-01-08    NULL     NULL
 9:  9 2015-01-09    NULL     NULL
10: 10 2015-01-10    NULL     NULL
```

into

```
    id   datadate charvar charvar1
 1:  1 2015-01-01       a        a
 2:  2 2015-01-02       b        b
 3:  3 2015-01-03       c        c
 4:  4 2015-01-04                d
 5:  5 2015-01-05                 
 6:  6 2015-01-06                 
 7:  7 2015-01-07                 
 8:  8 2015-01-08                 
 9:  9 2015-01-09                 
10: 10 2015-01-10
```

I tried two ways:

First method:

```
    df %>%
      mutate_if(is.character(.)==TRUE, 
                funs(function(col){col = if_else(col=='NULL', '', col)}))
```

from which I got the error:

```
          Error: length(.p) == length(vars) is not TRUE
```

Second method:

```
data.frame(
  lapply(df, function(col)
              {if(is.character(col)==TRUE) col = ifelse(col=='NULL', '', col)})
)
```

For which I got the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 10
```

What am I doing wrong here? Would appreciate insights into how to correct both methods and why the code above is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `df` is a `data.table`, you can modify specific rows by supplying `[.data.table` with a logical vector in `i` and assigning the new value in `j` e.g. `df[charvar == 'NULL', charvar := '']`. So you can `lapply` over all character columns to do that for each of them. This avoids using `ifelse`, and so avoids reassigning the entire column each time.

```
library(data.table)

lapply(names(df)[sapply(df, is.character)], #lapply over all character column names
       function(x) df[df[[x]] == 'NULL', (x) := '']) #set column equal to '' for rows where it equals 'NULL'
```

If you want to use `dplyr`, you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, 
            function(col) if_else(col == 'NULL', '', col))
```

In `tidyverse` (to the extent that it is consistent), `.` represents the left-hand side of the pipe `%>%`. So if you use `is.character(.)` as the first argument, `dplyr` will evaluate `is.character(df)`, which is `FALSE`,  a logical vector of length `1`. But `mutate_if` is expecting a logical vector of length `ncol(df)`, or a function.

Example data with > 1 character column.

```
df <- data.table('id' = seq(1:10),
                 'datadate' = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2015-01-10'), by="days"),
                 'charvar' = c('a', 'b', 'c', rep('NULL', 7)),
                 'charvar2' = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', rep('NULL', 7))) )
```

Comment: the first method gives a weird result that duplicates the df if I have more than one character variables. For example, if I apply it to a data.table with two character variables (see revised df in my original question). Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure. It works for me with the example `df` I just added to the answer, which has 2 character columns.

Comment: I'm trying to get back a data.frame or data.table, so I  wrapped data.frame() around your lapply, and that's why I got the result that I got. Your code returns a list of two elements. How should I modify it to get a data.frame or data.table?

Comment: Just ignore whatever it returns, because what it returns doesn't matter. You don't need to use `<-` to reassign the results to `df`, or wrap it in `data.frame`. You can just run the `lapply` code and your `df` will be changed.

Comment: OK I see, then how do I get it to not print out the result since my dataset is quiet big?

Comment: If you have `tidyverse` or `purrr` loaded you can do `lapply(...) %>% quietly`. It won't print out all the rows anyway though, `data.table` just prints a head and tail by default.

Comment: for your second method, I want to use more complicated conditions (more than is.character) then how should I reference the columns? For example, if I want to do `is.character==FALSE` I can't just say that, otherwise I would get an error. Or if I want to say is.character AND (the column name ends with 2), I would need to somehow reference the column or variable.

Comment: The first argument can be a logical vector of length `ncol(x)`, such as `%>% mutate_if(sapply(df, is.character) &  endsWith(names(df), '2'), ...)`